# How am I able to instantiate multiple Objects in a 2D array of 1D arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

So I'm trying to have an array of 2D arrays (so [,][])

They all return Null in the end though for some reason (Most likely due to no assigning to the array)

Edit1: Mistake fixed in code. Thanks.
Edit2: Fixed title, as it is in fact a 2D array of 1D arrays.

Example:

```
public Environment()
{
    _grid2D = new Object[20, 20][];
}
```

I also try to assign objects to them later in my code:

```
public GenerateGrid() 
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
    {
        obj = new InsertObject(rand.Next(0,19), rand.next(0,19));
        _grid2D[InsertObject.XPos, InsertObject.YPos][0] = obj;
    }
}
```

I am attempting to use this kind of array because I require seemingly multiple planes of 2D, that are kind of stacked on top of eachother. This way multiple game objects can technically exist in the same space, as the 2D array is an array that will contain positions (X and Y properties already defined elsewhere)

This may be a little convoluted, as there is maybe a better approach.

I need a 20x20 grid, with multiple planes of this grid.

Randomly deciding the location is a design choice, and when the time comes that there are multiple objects in the same location, I will check for this and prevent / reassign a location (rand again).

Comment: That's not an array of 2D arrays. It's a 2D array of 1D arrays. It's other things too, but this is a family-oriented web site.

Comment: I feel like this is an XY problem here. What are you trying to accomplish with this hodgepodge of 2D/1D arrays? Why not just use a 3D array?

Comment: *"Most likely due to no assigning to the array"* -- that's right. You need a loop that assigns `new object[2]` or something to each slot in `_grid2D`. How big does that innermost array need to be? You only every try to assign to the second item in it.

Comment: The next problem you'll run into is that you are creating `InsertObject`s with out of range indexes: An array of size 20 has valid indexes from zero (0) to nineteen (19), not 1..20. You're only using the `[1]` index in the inner array, which suggests that you think that's the first item in that array. It isn't. `[0]` is the first item in that array.

Comment: The next problem after that is that you seem to be creating `InsertObject`s at random locations, so depending on how the ball bounces you'll sometimes end up putting one at a given location, then randomly replacing it with another one later in the loop.

Comment: It's not that you're wasting space with 1-20, it's that the array doesn't have a 20th element and will throw an exception if you try to assign to it. It only has elements 0-19. Also, if you could respond in comments that would be better, as we get notifications if you @ us.

Comment: Sorry about that, I see, I'll use 0-19 in this case, and when should I be @'ing people in the comments, frequently? Or not so much @TJ Wolschon.

Comment: @Kalamata just whenever you want the person to see it. Example is with your latest comment you only pinged me and not Ed, so I got a notification for it while he didn't.

Comment: I need to head out for now, so I'll check the answers and experiment more with my code later on. Thanks everyone for taking your time. Just a quick note I'm not sure I want to use lists for this.

Comment: @Kalamata When you reply to somebody's comment, use @. If they're trying to help you, they'll want to know you responded. If they're not trying to help you, they shouldn't be commenting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, but I think what you are trying to do is to allow any number of "InsertObject" objects in each cell of the 2D array.  I'm guessing, based on your access pattern of randomly selecting x,y coordinates for each object as you add them to the grid.

If that is the case, then use a List in each cell of the grid.  If you want, you can allocate each List when you add the first item, and leave it sparse (so you don't create lists for cells with 0 objects in them.)  Or you can do a first pass where you populate all the cells of the 2D array with empty lists.  The strategy you go with depends on how much you care about efficiency, and whether you expect a sparse or dense population.

```
List<Object>[,] _grid2D = new List<Object>[20, 20];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int x = rand.Next(1, 20);
    int y = rand.Next(1, 19);
    Object obj = new object(); // Replace with your InsertObject here.
    if (_grid2D[x, y] == null) // If this cell's list doesn't exist yet...
    {
        _grid2D[x, y] = new List<Object>(); /// ... then make one.
    }
    _grid2D[x, y].Add(obj); // Add the object to the list.
}
```

Just be careful when accessing the grid if you go with this sparse technique, as some grid cells may have no List created if they have 0 objects (_grid2D[x,y] may be null).

---

And if you *don't* want to allow multiple objects per grid cell, then you just need a 2D array of InsertObject objects.  `InsertObject[,] _grid2D = new InsertObject[20,20];`

Answer (score 0):

Two different implementations one with a 3D array and another is a list of 2D arrays

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numberOfPanes = 50;
        var myGrid1 = GenerateGrid1(20, 20, numberOfPanes);
        var myGrid2 = GenerateGrid2(20, 20, numberOfPanes);


    }

    public static Object[,,] GenerateGrid1(int x, int y, int numberOfPanes)
    {
        var grid = new Object[x, y, numberOfPanes];            

        Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

        for (int k = 0; k < numberOfPanes; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                {
                    grid[i, j, k] = rand.Next(1, 20);
                }
            }
        }

        return grid;
    }


    public static List<int[,]> GenerateGrid2(int x, int y, int numberOfPanes)
    {
        var grid = new int[x, y];
        var multiPanes = new List<int[,]>();

        Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

        for (int k = 0; k < numberOfPanes; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                {
                    grid[i, j] = rand.Next(1, 20);
                }
            }

            multiPanes.Add(grid);
        }

        return multiPanes;
    }
```